# HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: ajax, importing-exporting

When using a field collection feed import, I get this error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /batch?id=17839&op=do StatusText: OK
>   ResponseText: Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
>   is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Cannot
>   modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
>   {"status":true,"percentage":"64","message":""}

I have researched this issue and statistically came up with this solution: change in php.ini always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

I have changed that and also restarted apache.

I still receive that error. Does anyone have any thoughts to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `php.ini` and add or uncomment the following line:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

If you've still that error after restarting Apache, you probably edited the wrong file. So as admin, go to *Reports*/*Status*/*PHP* (at `/admin/reports/status/php`) and double-check your value for `always_populate_raw_post_data` and your `php.ini` path.

Note that the above setting will only avoid the warning, see: [Changes to PHP-5.6](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/slim_post_data#changes_to_php-56) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26261001/55075).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should be disabled.

There is [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2456025) on this in the core Drupal queue.